# Dead code using android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, dead-code

I am working on android application in which i am using a logic to find the direction of a person from coordinated. Everything is working fine but i got error at console: : "Dead Code". My code is given below, please explain me this thing.

```
private void direction() {

        String userLocation = mLatitude + ","
                + mLongitude ;

        if(userLocation!=null){
            String distLocation = Constants.sMY_LOCATION.getLatitude() + ","
                    + Constants.sMY_LOCATION.getLongitude();
            String url = "https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&saddr=" + userLocation
                    + "&daddr=" + distLocation;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }else{ // Getting Dead Code Yellow error here
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please check your internet and try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
```

Comment: `Dead Code` is code you don't use anymore, such as a method which is never called. It is **not an error**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because your else can't be reached

```
String userLocation = mLatitude + ","
            + mLongitude ;

    if(userLocation!=null){
       ...
    }else{
       ...
    }
```

userLocation will never be null

Answer (score 2):

The code in your else{} will never be reached because your string userLocation is initialized before the if statement, meaning it will never be null.

So the code in you else is effectively dead code.

Answer (score 1):

You should check `mLatitude` and `mLongitude` for being null instead of whole String.

Example:

```
if (mLatitude != null && mLongitude != null) {
   // String userLocation = ...
}
else {
   // Your else code
}
```